# FInd indexes of matching rows in two matrices of different size

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say you have a matrix:

```
a=matrix(1:6, nrow = 2, byrow=TRUE)
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
```

and b:

```
b=matrix(c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
> b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    7    8    9
[3,]   10   11   12
[4,]    1    2    3
```

How do you find the indexes of the corresponding rows of matrix "a" in "b"?
The result indexes for this small example should be:  4, 1

Take in mind that I am doing a dummy example, my matrixes are very large (1M X 64).
The entries are unique, so there is only one line of matrix "b" that correspond to matrix "a".
The language is R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also combine `duplicated` and `which` after `rbind`-ing `b` and `a` :

```
which(duplicated(rbind(b, a), fromLast = TRUE))
# [1] 1 4
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `match` from `base R`

```
match(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(a)), do.call(paste, as.data.frame(b)))
#[1] 4 1
```